# jQuery animated number counter from zero to value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, each

I have created a script to animate a number from zero to it's value.

### Working

**jQuery**

```js
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({
  Counter: $('.Single').text()
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function() {
    $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single">150</span>
```

---

### Not Working

I now want to run the script several times on the page for each matching class.

Below is what I am trying but with no success so far:

**HTML**

```
<span class="Count">200</span>
<span class="Count">55</span>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.Count').each(function () {
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $(this).text() }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Your `this`doesn't refer to the element in the step callback, instead you want to keep a reference to it at the beginning of your function (wrapped in `$this`in my example):

```
$('.Count').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});
```

**Update**: If you want to display decimal numbers, then instead of rounding the value with `Math.ceil` you can round up to 2 decimals for instance with `value.toFixed(2)`:

```
step: function () {
  $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: what if we've decimal numbers?

Comment: @VilasKumkar I know this is an old thread, but for future Googlers, here's how I tweaked the answer to handle decimals, as well as prefix and postfix (for example, "$12.34 Million" (I'm sure it could be cleaner): https://gist.github.com/ashicus/b18f2831d7d21fc10fe2e47c41922328

Comment: I've also updated my answer with a way to print numbers with any number of decimals

Comment: Thanks for the good snippet @floribon. What i could do for not writing the code twice if i wanna do count down after doing count up with the same code? Any idea?

Comment: I cannot get the fiddle fiddle that @Obsidian posted to work with a decimal, `100.50` shows up as `101`, tried using @ashicus and @floribon code but doesn't work, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how to swing it continuously.

Comment: add `.toLocaleString()` to `$this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter).toLocaleString());` to get comma separated/local formatted string.

Answer (score 22):

`this` inside the step callback isn't the element but the object passed to animate()

```
$('.Count').each(function (_, self) {
    jQuery({
        Counter: 0
    }).animate({
        Counter: $(self).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            $(self).text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
    });
});
```

Another way to do this and keep the references to `this` would be

```
$('.Count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MbRE9/2/)

Answer (score 16):

**IMPORTANT**: It seems like a small difference but you should really use a data attribute to hold the original number to count up to.  Altering the original number can have un-intended consequences.  For instance, I'm having this animation run everytime an element enters the screen.  But if the element enters, exits, and then enters the screen a second time before the first animation finishes, it will count up to the wrong number.

HTML:

```
<p class="count" data-value="200" >200</p>
<p class="count" data-value="70" >70</p>
<p class="count" data-value="32" >32</p>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).data('value')
        }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {                      
            $(this).text(this.Counter.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the exact issue I was having with the above.

Comment: I also added `done: function () { $this.text($this.data('value').toLocaleString()); }` to ensure the final value is correct.

Answer (score 5):

What the code does, is that the number 8000 is counting up from 0 to 8000. The problem is, that it is placed at the middle of quite long page, and once user scroll down and actually see the number, the animation is already dine. I would like to trigger the counter, once it appears in the viewport.

JS:

```
$('.count').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                        Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                        duration: 4000,
                        easing: 'swing',
                        step: function (now) {
                                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                        }
                });
            });
```

And HTML:

```
 <span class="count">8000</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution 
and it's also working, when element shows into the viewport

---

You can see the code in action by clicking [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uosahmed/frLoxm34/9/)

```
var counterTeaserL = $('.go-counterTeaser');
var winHeight = $(window).height();
if (counterTeaserL.length) {
    var firEvent = false,
        objectPosTop = $('.go-counterTeaser').offset().top;

        //when element shows at bottom
        var elementViewInBottom = objectPosTop - winHeight;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var currentPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        //when element position starting in viewport
      if (currentPosition > elementViewInBottom && firEvent === false) {
        firEvent = true;
        animationCounter();
      }   
    });
}

//counter function will animate by using external js also add seprator "."
 function animationCounter(){
        $('.numberBlock h2').each(function () {
            var comma_separator_number_step =           $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.separator('.');
            var counterValv = $(this).text();
            $(this).animateNumber(
                {
                  number: counterValv,
                  numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
                }
            );
        });
    }


https://jsfiddle.net/uosahmed/frLoxm34/9/
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna handle based on if it is int or float

```js
$(".display-counter").each(function () {
    $(this)
      .prop("Counter", 0)
      .animate(
        {
          Counter: $(this).text()
        },
        {
          duration: 4000,
          easing: "swing",
          step: function (now, tween) {
            // Check added for decimal number
            if(parseInt(tween.end) == parseFloat(tween.end)){
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            } else{
              $(this).text(now.toFixed(2));
            }
          },
        }
      );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="display-counter">123</p>
<p class="display-counter">125.3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element itself in `.each()`, try this instead of using `this`

```
$('.Count').each(function (index, value) {
    jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: value.text() }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            value.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

HTML CODE

```
<span class="number-count">841</span>
```

jQuery Code

```
$('.number-count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with animate function in jQuery.

```
$({ countNum: $('.code').html() }).animate({ countNum: 4000 }, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function () {
        $('.yourelement').html(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('.code').html(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
   }
});
```

[Demo](https://www.geekinsta.com/animated-number-counter-using-jquery/)

Comment: I like this answer, because it has complete method inside. When dealing with big numbers, one can set the final number to be sure it is the value it should be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        countnumber(0,40,"stat1",50);
        function countnumber(start,end,idtarget,duration){
            cc=setInterval(function(){
                if(start==end)
                {
                    $("#"+idtarget).html(start);
                    clearInterval(cc);
                }
                else
                {
                   $("#"+idtarget).html(start);
                   start++;
                }
            },duration);
        }
    });
</script>
<span id="span1"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
$('.Count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({
      Counter: $('.Single').text()
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function() {
        $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
      }
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span class="Single">150</span>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my stone to the edifice ! The following code trigger the counter with an intersection observer:

```js
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
        if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true){
            $('.Counter').each(function() {
                $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 1500,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function(now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.Counter').each(function() {
                $(this).stop(); // Stop the animation if the element is not intersecting
                let initial = $(this).data('value');
                $(this).text(initial);
            });
        }
            
    }, { threshold: [1] }); 
    // You can move the threshold between 0 to 1. 0 is the very top of the element
    
    observer.observe(document.getElementById("counter"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
  <span data-value="30" class="Counter">30</span>
  <span data-value="350" class="Counter">350</span>
  <span data-value="1500000" class="Counter">1500000</span>
</div>
```