# Jquery animation number from to

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a problem with that animation I found here : 
[jQuery animated number counter from zero to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006516/jquery-animated-number-counter-from-zero-to-value?newreg=7502800c79c94ff383401d50f437abb8)

Here is the problem, I used it on test website and the counter don't go on the exact value when it's with big numbers.

here's the HTML :

```
<span class="Count">66620</span>
 <br/>
<span class="Count">66666666</span>
 <br/>
<span class="Count">66666666</span>
```

here's the javascript :

```
$('.Count').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6r6/68/

Do someone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply use the first argument of the callback?

> **step**
>
> Type: Function( Number now, Tween tween )

```
step: function (i) {
    $this.text(Math.ceil(i));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6r6/70/

Comment: Because It was too simple ><. No seriously i did not think about that possibility :'(.
thanks !