# Trigger jQuery animated number counter on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to get this jQuery animated counter to trigger as soon as the user scrolls more than 200 pixels down the page:

Original jQuery code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006516/jquery-animated-number-counter-from-zero-to-value)

```
$('.Count').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried to wrap it in the following jQuery but it doesn't trigger the animation until the end:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('.Count').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function () {
                    $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="Count">100</span>
<br/>
<span class="Count">200</span>
<br/>
<span class="Count">300</span>
```

The fiddle from the other post is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6r6/3/)

What would be the best way to trigger the jQuery counter as soon as the user scrolls into view or 200 pixels down the page? I've also tried the jQuery Wayfinder but not had any luck with making it work.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6r6/420/  What do you mean by "it doesn't trigger the animation until the end"?  The end of what?

Comment: It doesn't work @gilly3 - scroll down and the numbers just flick between 1 and 0 - I'd like them to count up from 0 when the user scrolls down (e.g 200 pixels down)

Comment: If you keep scrolling after the animation has started, the animation restarts.  The animation gets the end value from the current value in the div.  Since the animation is currently in progress, the number will be lower.  This is why you are seeing it flick between 1 and 0.  You restarted the animation shortly after the animation began and had only gotten to 1.  Lot's of ways to fix this.  How many times do you want the animation to run?  Just once?  Every time?

Comment: Just want the animation to run once @gilly3 as soon as the user scrolls down 200 pixels so they see the numbers being animated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unbind the scroll handler (with `$(window).off("scroll")`) before triggering the animation to prevent the animation from restarting if the user continues to scroll.

```js
$(window).scroll(startCounter);
function startCounter() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $(window).off("scroll", startCounter);
        $('.Count').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function () {
                    $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 300vh;
}
.Count {
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Count">100</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to trigger it when it scrolls past a certain class or id instead of when it scrolls down 200 pixels? @gilly3

Comment: Instead of hard coding `200`, use `$(window).scrollTop() > $("#someElement").offset().top()`

Comment: I tried  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#someElement").offset().top()) { and it doesn't work @gilly3 (also put the id on the element)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, no parentheses for `.top`.  It should be `$(window).scrollTop() > $("#someElement").offset().top`.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6r6/422/)

Comment: $(window).off("scroll"); has caused my nav bar active state to stop being highlighted when selected - is there another way to stop it conflicting with the nav bar a tag active state?

Comment: If you have multiple scroll handlers, you'll have to switch from anonymous functions to named functions in order to only unbind the function you want via `$(window).off("scroll", myFunction)`.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Gilly's answer is a good one,
but it's missing the part for making it start at 0 and get to a certain  value;

this is what you could do:

```js
var stop = $("#someElement").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stop ) {
            $(window).off("scroll");
            $('.Count').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.attr("data") }, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function () {
                        $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 300vh;
}
.Count {
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Count" data=200>0</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to trigger it when it scrolls past a certain class or id instead of when it scrolls down 200 pixels? @maioman

Comment: I edited the snippet and it won't work , but the theory is: you get the value of the id offset and then set in ($(window).scrollTop() > stop )

Comment: $(window).off("scroll"); has caused my nav bar active state to stop being highlighted when selected - is there another way to stop it conflicting with the nav bar a tag active state?

Answer (score 1):

maybe a little late, but this code works when you get at the bottom of the page

```
jQuery(         
    function($)
    {
        var banderaEstandar= true;
        $('#vista').on('scroll', function()
        {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight && banderaEstandar)
            {
                $('.count').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate(
                {
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, 
                {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
                });
                });
                banderaEstandar=false;
            }
        })
    }
    );
```