# jQuery number counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this jQuery snippet to animate a number counter from 0 to to the number provided in the span. Could someone show me how to modify it to get numbers to count DOWN to 0 when starting at a given value?

```
<span class="count">200</span>

$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Spans don't have a 'Counter' property. You may want to look into data attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery animated number counter from zero to value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006516/jquery-animated-number-counter-from-zero-to-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  I'm assuming that 'now' in the step function is just counting steps.

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).data('start', parseInt($(this).text())).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text($(this).data(start) - now);
        }
    });
});
```

I verified this works in jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/0mtht3xm/):

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).data('start', parseInt($(this).text())).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text($(this).data('start') - Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are countless different ways to create a counter that counts down to 0. This is just how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<span class="count">200</span>
```

JS:

```
var $count = $('.count');

var num = parseInt($count.text());
var interval = window.setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

function updateTime() {
  num--;
  $count.text(num.toString());
  if (num <= 0) {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```