# Animated number counter from 0 to a PHP value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website and there I fetch the number of users online on my Discord server like this:

```
<?php
$members = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/356230556738125824/widget.json'), true)['members'];
$membersCount = 1;
foreach ($members as $member) {
        $membersCount++;
}
?>
```

And then display it like:

```
<p><?=$membersCount?></p>
```

It works fine without problem.

The problem is I don't want it to instantly pop up the amount of users online, I want it to smoothly transition from zero to the returned PHP value.

I have never tinkered with PHP / HTML and such before so I thought that this might be fun.

Comment: The question is about [tag:javascript] and [tag:html] and not related to PHP in any way.

Comment: Also you can use `count($members)` instead of `foreach` loop.

Comment: first take a class in your paragraph then through jquery you can animate that

Comment: You can use jQuery for that, see [jQuery animated number counter from zero to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006516/jquery-animated-number-counter-from-zero-to-value)

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/m4mjjw80/

Comment: @sinisake That works perfectly thank you!