# How to make label display like number counter animation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a project that is lucky system,but i don't know how to make label display like number counter animation. The label is employee id from text file.Below are my code.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Random random = new Random();
    private string testFilePath = @"C:\Users\Nor  Asyraf  Mohd No\Documents\TestFile.txt";
    private List<string> testFileLines;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(testFilePath))
        {
            Response.Write($"The file does not exist: {testFilePath}");

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                testFileLines = File.ReadAllLines(testFilePath).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write($"Could not read file {testFilePath}. Exception details: {ex}");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (testFileLines != null && testFileLines.Count > 0)
        {
            var randomLine = testFileLines[random.Next(testFileLines.Count)];
            Label1.Text = randomLine;
            testFileLines.Remove(randomLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "display like lottery" mean? Can you give some example of how you want it to appear? Are you talking about random numbers? Or how they are ordered? The font?

Comment: Yes..like a random number but i want the result moving/rolling  like others lucky draw system.

Comment: You want it random and animated is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes @MichaelPuckettII

Comment: It is like number counter animation

Comment: Can you adapt the code from this question [jQuery animated number counter from zero to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006516/jquery-animated-number-counter-from-zero-to-value)?

Comment: Yes,it work but why it cannot read a few data in my notepad.It only read numbers. Example of data that cannot be read is "INT2022".

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.Count').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('Counter','').animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
        });
</script>`