# jQuery animated number counter from zero to value - counter shows wrong value when a value is hundreds of thousands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, each

I have tried to animate the numbers with the help of this URL: [jQuery animated number counter from zero to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006516/jquery-animated-number-counter-from-zero-to-value) and followed this code:

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is, I gave a number 800 000  to increment in the numeric counter. Randomly this value is incremented and decremented again to 0. For e.g. After incrementing the value up to 800 000, it is again animating back to value 0.

Counter for zero to value is working fine for smaller values in thousands.

Answer (score 1):

While researching how to do it, I realized that all solutions in the stack are with jquery. Now I write native (vanillajs) in projects, my solution is as follows.

```js
var getCountItems = document.querySelectorAll('.count-item');
if(getCountItems){
    getCountItems.forEach(function (countItem) {
        var counterValueElement = countItem.querySelector('strong');
        var storeCurrentValue = parseInt(counterValueElement.textContent);

        var fromZero = 0;

        if(fromZero === 0){
            counterValueElement.textContent = "0";
        }

        setInterval(function () {
            if(++fromZero <= storeCurrentValue){
                counterValueElement.textContent = fromZero.toString();
            }
        }, 15); // set your speed (decrease)
    });
}
```

```css
section#countdown{
    margin: 50px 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #1C1E23;
}

section#countdown h3{
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

section#countdown h3:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
    height: 1px;
    width: 80%;
    background: rgba(28, 30, 35, 0.44);
}

section#countdown .count-item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgba(28, 30, 35, 0.7);
    margin: 15px 0;
    /* set your anim count text for "all" */
    transition: all .3s ease, color .4s ease-in;
}

section#countdown .count-item:hover{
    transform: scale(1.25);
    color: #C22429;
}

section#countdown .count-item span{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgba(28, 30, 35, 0.44);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
    section#countdown h3 + div{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    section#countdown .count-item{
        transform: scale(1.5);
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="countdown" class="box-p">
    <h3>STATISTICS</h3>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around">
        <div class="count-item">
            <strong>47</strong>
            <span>YEAR EXPERIENCE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="count-item">
            <strong>100</strong>
            <span>EXPORT COUNTRIES</span>
        </div>
        <div class="count-item">
            <strong>200</strong>
            <span>BRANDS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="count-item">
            <strong>500</strong>
            <span>EMPLOYEE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="count-item">
            <strong>7</strong>
            <span>SUB BRANDS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="count-item">
            <strong>2</strong>
            <span>FACTORY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**UPDATE**

Added, Pure JS version below the code;

```
var getCountItems = document.getElementsByClassName('count-item');
for(var i = 0; i < getCountItems.length; i++){
    let item = getCountItems[i];

    let counterValueElement = item.children[0]; // strong
    let storeCurrentValue = parseInt(counterValueElement.textContent);

    let fromZero = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
        if(fromZero <= storeCurrentValue){
            counterValueElement.textContent = (fromZero++).toString();
        }
    }, 15); // set your speed (decrease)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick,

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 8000)
    .animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now, a) {
        $(this).text(8000 - ~~this.Counter);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='count'>0</span>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: $('.count').each(function () {
          $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).data('value')
              }, {
              duration: 3000,
              easing: 'swing',
              step: function (now) {                      
                  $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
              }
          });
      });

Actually this works fine for me. I used data-value to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Miroslav Glamuzina.