# jQuery/JS number counting animation from zero to value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a web-app in which the HTML code receives an integer value from python. I want to add a counting from 0 to that number animation.
I have checked many such queries on StackOverflow like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006516/jquery-animated-number-counter-from-zero-to-value).

Today morning the animation was working fine, but now it's not working.

```js
$('.count').each(function () 
{
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate
    ({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, 
    {
        duration: 10000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) 
        {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="font-weight-bold" style="color:#f92424"><span class="count">{{ confirmedIn }}</span></h4>
```

Maybe I am missing some library or something, idk

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: @Denis, I updated the jquery library as per edition. but now the garbage values are animating and not the values that I put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing your code:

Since the there is no logic to dictate how the counter should change, i've added a `countTo` variable before the animation.

Since you reference `{ Counter: $(this).text() }` as the properties object within the animate function, the `$(this).text()` begins as `{{ confirmed }}` which is not a parsable number, hence `NaN`.

The solution below should resolve this.

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
    let el = $(this);
    let countTo = 1000;
    
    el.prop('counter',0).animate({
        counter: `+=${countTo}`
    }, {
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now))
        },

    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="font-weight-bold" style="color:#f92424"><span class="count">{{ confirmedIn }}</span></h4>
```

Comment: But many values are dynamic passed from python. Isn't there any way, I could animate that?

Comment: Honestly that’s a different question... check *how do I pass a python variable to jQuery