# countTo very slow on Safari

Tags: jquery

I have this code that counts up from 1 to 2 with decimals, and it works fine across all browsers expect on Safari, it loads very slow and ignores the speed setup.

If you open it in Chrome it works fine, but if you open in Safari it's super slow.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

    // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
      increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

    return $(this).each(function() {
      var _this = this,
        loopCount = 0,
        value = options.from,
        interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

      function updateTimer() {
        value += increment;
        loopCount++;
        $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

        if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
          options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
        }

        if (loopCount >= loops) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          value = options.to;

          if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
            options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 1.0, // the number the element should start at
    to: 2.0, // the number the element should end at
    speed: 300, // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 1, // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 1, // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null, // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null, // callback method for when the element finishes updating
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.counter-up').countTo({
    from: 1.00,
    to: 2.00,
    decimals: 1,
    speed: 300,
    refreshInterval: 1
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h1 class="counter-up">
  1.0
</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tu92d7on/

Comment: The are better (and more succinct) methods of animating a counter in jQuery. For example this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23006516/519413. I'd suggest trying that in your Safari instance to see if it performs better